# Correct way to inject and use a named function in a class / object?

Tags: php, class, dependency-injection

What's the common practice when one needs to inject a normal, named function in a class / object? I can inject an anonymous function / closure created with `function() {}` but most of the times I may prefer traditional static functions.

For instance, I want to inject a named function as `Some::func()` in the class `Test`. Do I just pass in the name of the function as a string? Or is there any other better way?

This is what I come up with thus far:

```
class Test {
    private $func;
    public function __construct($func) {
        $this -> func = array(
            'name' => $func
        );
    }
    public function run() {
        $this -> func['name']();
    }
    public function run2() {
        Some::func();
    }
    public function run3() {
        call_user_func_array($this -> func['name'], array());
    }
}

class Some {
    static function func() {
        echo 'Success!';
    }
}

$test = new Test('Some::func');
$test -> run(); // Call to undefined function Some::func()
$test -> run2(); // Works!
$test -> run3(); // Works!
```

The first `run()` looks much better albeit not working. And the error sounds weird to me because `Some::func()` is definitely defined in there as the other ways work properly.

Seems to me `call_user_func_array()` is the only way here? Is there any way I can make the first approach `run()` work? If not, why?

Comment: Your "normal, named function" is a static method. So using `call_user_func_array` or `call_user_func` is the way to go. More info:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @bitWorking inspired me. It seems can be done this way:

```
$test = new Test(array('Some', 'func'));
$test -> run(); // Works!
$test -> run2(); // Works!
$test -> run3(); // Works!
```

Instead of passing `'Some::func'`, one should pass `array('Some', 'func')` for this.